# KSP-like interactive map of the real solar system?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

So Kerbal Space Program's map view is one of the greatest tools for visualising trajectories and the relative position of bodies and spacecraft I've ever seen.

Does anyone know if someone's produced a similar tool for the *real* solar system, regularly updated with information for all the various spacecraft and probes that we've launched so far? It would make it so much simpler to see at a glance, e.g., the F9 station rendezvous mission profile (which I've just failed to find information on online).

Screenshot follows; for those who don't know KSP, the blue arc is the currently selected object's trajectory, the asterisk marks a manoeuvre, the dotted arc is the trajectory after the manoeuvre, the green arc is the target object, the red and blue markers show various closest-approach information, etc, etc. The player here is planning an orbital rendezvous. The circular object at the bottom is for controlling the player's ship and not relevant to the question.

[image: ObScreenshot]

Comment: There's many such tools. Try [NASA's "Eyes on the Solar System"](http://eyes.nasa.gov/).

Comment: Added screenshot and writeup. And unfortunately 'Eyes on the Solar System' only works on Windows and OSX, so it won't let me see it.

Comment: Then please include that info also as a requirement in your question. I still don't get it what exactly you're looking for (title says "map", question "tool"). You'd like to visualize the Solar system and spacecraft trajectories? There's literally hundreds if not thousands of such applications, most written in Java so they'd technically work on most operating systems, and would let you select epoch and import ephemeris. Then there's always the paid for tools that come with all the bells and whistles. Does it have to be freeware? Also, why can't you run it in [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)?

Comment: Oh, you thought I meant a _static_ map? Updated for clarity. Also re those thousand packages... I'm asking this question _because_ there are a thousand packages (most of which are junk).

Comment: You might try Orbiter; it appears to run in Wine.https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2269

Comment: There is https://eyes.nasa.gov/ which has some elements of this, but I haven't used it enough to know it's full capabilities. You can speed up and slow down time and watch various missions and do other things, but I don't think you can add your own missions to it. Not sure though.

Comment: Have you tried [Celestia](https://celestiaproject.net)?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is [a mod for KSP called Real Solar System](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/50471-12-real-solar-system-v120-dec-8/) which replaces the default with our real one.

Aside from that, the Universe Sandbox game might be an alternative, a very good simulator.